# "Assumptions" is a noun, can I use "they" to refer to it?

Tags: nouns, attributive-nouns

If I refer to "assumptions" in one statement, can someone else refer to "assumptions" as *they* in his/her answer?

For example:

> He: Assumptions can be true as well.
>
> She: No, they are not.

Answer (score 2):

*They* is indeed the correct pronoun to use in place of the word *assumptions*. In the same way a single assumption could be replaced with the singular pronoun *it*.

There is however a mistake in your example that is not related to the pronoun.  Person one (he) is not stating assumptions **are** true as well, but that assumptions **can be** true as well. The response from person two (she) should also be conditional:

He : Assumptions can be true as well.

She : No, they **can** not.

Answer (score 0):

*Assumption* has a countable meaning: *something that is believed to be true or probably true but that is not known to be true : something that is assumed*.

We cannot refer to *assumption* as *they*, but we can refer to *assumptions* as *they*.

My assumption is that he will arrive by plane.
--It's a good assumption, in my opinion.

Your assumptions were wrong.
--Yes, **they** were gravely mistaken.